# How can I loop through the values of a drop down within a SuperTable?

Tags: templating, plugin-supertable

I a musing a front-end form to create an entry in the CP. In my form I am using a [SuperTable](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable) that contains two fields/blocks.

- Size - [text input]
- Measurement - [dropdown]

Here is what my template looks like:

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[lotSize]">
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[lotSize][new1][type]" value="1">

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lotSize">Lot Size</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fields[lotSize][new1][fields][size]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="measurement">Measurement</label>
        <select name="fields[lotSize][new1][fields][measurement]">
            {# Loop through the values instead of hard-coding #}
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="squareFeet">Square Feet</option>
            <option value="acres">Acres</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been reading through [Updating a Super Table field from a front end form](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable/wiki/Updating-a-Super-Table-field-from-a-front-end-form) and have tried this:

```
{% set fieldHandle = 'lotSize' %}
{% set field = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle(fieldHandle) %}
{% set blocktype = craft.superTable.getSuperTableBlocks(field.id)[0] %}
```

...But I'm not sure where to go next to get to the `measurement` field.

I have attached a screenshot of my CP page to help show what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you for any suggestions!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely want to do something like this:

```
{% for fieldtype in blocktype.getFieldLayout.fields %}
    {% set field = fieldtype.field %}

    Handle: {{ field.handle }}

    {% if field.type == 'Dropdown' %}
        {% for option in field.settings.options %}
            Label: {{ option.label }}
            Value: {{ option.value }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Essentially, this loops through all the sub-fields in your Super Table field, and for each field, you can make any sort of conditional you like in order to handle each fields content.

Comment: Exactly the shove I needed. `{% if field.type == 'Dropdown' %}` was it. Thank you!